# How to access bigquery from shiny app

Tags: r, google-bigquery, shiny

I am trying to build a shiny app that needs to access my bigquery tables, it works fine locally through interactive authentication.

Whey I deploy the app it does not work giving the error:

> Error: oauth_listener() needs an interactive environment.

There is a suggestion here - [Authorization for accessing BigQuery from R session on server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33168363/authorization-for-accessing-bigquery-from-r-session-on-server), but I don't know how to pass the `.httr-oauth` file to shinyapps.io

Comment: `?deployApp` and note the `appFiles` parameter. Be super careful abt loading credential files onto servers you don't control.

Comment: Getting an error: `The project should have one of the following layouts: 1. 'shiny.R' and 'ui.R' in the application base directory,.. `  What should be in the appFiles?

Answer (score 1):

The way it was resolved is you need to generate access token json file in Google Cloud IAM with relevant access to BigQuery resources.

This file should be placed in your `appDir` folder and referenced in code, e.g.:

with `bigrquery` package

```
library(bigrquery)
set_service_token('access_token.json')

tb <- bq_dataset_query(
   x = ds,
   query = sql,
   billing = '{your billing project}',
   use_legacy_sql = use.legacy.sql,
   parameters = params
)
dt <- bq_table_download(tb)
```

, or with `retl` package:

```
# set env var `BIGQUERY_ACCESS_TOKEN_PATH` to path of your token file.
devtools::install_github(madedotcom/retl)
library(retl)
library(data.table)
dt <- bqExecuteQuery(sql)
```